# Woocommerce shop page as a main page programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on eshop (woocommerce) and I need to define the shop page as a main page but only for one language.

For instance if myshop.com is browse by someone from Czech Republic, I want to define the shop page as an homepage. If someone is from Germany he see a normal homepage.

The reason:

I can't just redirect Czech customers, because they couldn't see homepage after.

And I can't save session or make something like this because I want them to see the shop page all the time as an home page, not only once.

Comment: home page is always something without a url slug, in wordpress… maybe… i haven't tried yet. what you didn't tell in your question, is what are you going to use for managing languages?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea:

- When user is from Czech and come to the home page a coockie is set for 30 mn before it's redirected to the shop page.
- Once on the shop page the Czech user can go to the home page before the cookie expiration time.

The code:

**In function.php file**

```
// function for shortening language ID
function wplang() {
    $lang = get_bloginfo('language').'';
    $lang = explode("-", $lang);
    return $lang[0];
}
```

**In header.php file** (at the beginning). You have to set the correct url…

```
<?php     
    // Only for Czech users
    if ( wplang() == 'cz' )
    {
        czcookie = $_COOKIE['wpczech'];

        // if a valid cookie isn't set to 'cz' value
        if ( czcookie != 'cz' )
        {
            // Set a cookie for 30 mn with 'cz' value
            setcookie('wpczech', 'cz', time()+1800, null, null , false , true);
￼            
            // redirecting to shop page
            header('Location: url_of_your_cz_shop_page');
        }
    }
?>
```

The code has to be adapted and tested…

Comment: Thank you! It's great idea, but I just wonder if it's possible to change current home page to /blog and then change main page to shop in settings.