# Wordpress home page accessing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, redirect

Yesterday I asked this question but I think I bad posed my question and I still didn't solve it.

Therefore I'm trying to describe my problem a bit more:

I am developing website on wordpress using woocommerce. And I need to set my SHOP page as a HOME page. And everything would be fine if I just set it in settings, e.g. set Homepage as an static page or redirect it.

But I need to add Home page to menu and access it from shop page after clicking it in MENU.

So the question is: Are there any posibilities to change Main page SLUG for instance to `/blog` so I could redirect `/` to shop and then add to menu `/blog` link to access HOME page ?

*(now I'm using cookies and redirect users only once but it's not the best solution)*

Comment: Hi You need to create "shop" page as home page .. am i right ?

Comment: your question is not clear...

Comment: I dont really understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry for bad formulated question, maybe my yesturady question could help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725047/woocommerce-shop-page-as-a-main-page-programaticaly

I need to make "home page" as "shop page" and allow "home page" from "/blog" slug.

Comment: Also, please give information about how you handle languages in your web site (WPML, qTranslate …).